# Navbar title become small when scroll down and go back from a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The main navigation bar become small when go back from a table view with scrolling. Can anyone show me the correct way to implement large title?

Video Sample
https://i.imgur.com/zoATpja.gif

ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

DestinationViewController

```
let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

let array = ["Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.title = "TableView"
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: By default you want large titles in navigation bar?

Comment: ya, but when push to the destination view controller, I want it the small navigation bar

Comment: @MayurKarmur But the animation in 'Settings' of iPhone looks good

Comment: When you coming back from destination controller your testing title in navigation bar should be small, that whay you want?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav, I think the gif have cut some of the scene. Actually the ViewController has a large title, when I scroll the tableview at DestinationViewController, and go back immediately, it will become small

Comment: Then you want ViewController title always large in size, right?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav let me re-upload the gif

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav ya

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav this is my project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NbYRsr6ky5-ylaWZe7bDNO1tU4WfPbhZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you check with answer? @Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after tinkering with the issue, I've come to a conclusion that:

**This is probably a bug when using Large titles in combination with `UIViewController`.**

Then I found in one of your comments: ***but iPhone Settings and App Store has the similar animation...***

But the thing is that both of the reference apps uses `UITableViewController` subclass for the source (of the `segue`) view controller when the navigation happens. So I tried similar approach and **YES** my doubt is correct. You can find the [reference project here](https://github.com/M-I-N/LargeTitle) where the animation issue isn't present.

---

So, you might want to change your source view controller to be a subclass of `UITableViewController` until there is an official fix for the issue.

Comment: , I have found the solution and I have posted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This helps you!!

**Call this method from viewDidLoad()**

```
/**
In Swift 4.2
*/
 func setupNavBar() {

            self.title = "titleName"
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always        
     }
```

**In DestinationView Controller put this two lines in ViewDidLoad method.**

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

Comment: It's still the same https://i.imgur.com/zoATpja.gif, when it go back it become small, then return to large, when I scroll down the tableview. How can I fix it?

Comment: What you write in destinationViewController about navigation bar title remove that.

Comment: I need a small title in DestinationViewController and large title in ViewController, I have done both of this, my problem is when you scroll down the table view and go back immediately, the navigation bar will become small and return to large after that, u can try run in your actual device https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NbYRsr6ky5-ylaWZe7bDNO1tU4WfPbhZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What you wrote in DestinationViewController self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never remove this line.

Comment: But I want a small title on DestinationViewController, how can I achieve?

Comment: Check my answer @Sean If it works Please upward the answer!! Thanks

Comment: I have tried your code, but the problem is the animation, when u go back with holding the scroll of table view, it will cause the problem.

Comment: What you want you can achieve from this answer, only follow these steps!

Comment: oh, thanks @Abhishek Jadhav, but the problem is the **animation**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

and this

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

in `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy, The large title(ViewController) and small title(DestinationViewController) works fine, the problem is when you scroll down the table view and go back immediately, the navigation bar will become small and return to large after that, u can try run in your actual device https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NbYRsr6ky5-ylaWZe7bDNO1tU4WfPbhZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, it looks like UI glitch on apple's side. I doubt you can do anything with that.

Comment: Ya, at first I think it's a glitch, but iPhone Settings and App Store has the similar animation, and both of them work fine